# While using pygame my window closes instantly after running my program

Tags: python, pygame

```py
import sys
import pygame

from settings import Settings

class AlienInvasion:

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit
            
            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
            pytgame.display.flip  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game
```

Why does my display close after a split second? I edited the code. Its running the game now but the window wont stay open, is it an issue in my while true loop?

Comment: this is not enough code to even open a winodw... where do you call `AlienInvasion`? do you ever call `run_game` on the instance of that class? you also are not calling quite a bunch of other names, like it should be `pygame.display.flip()`, also no need to use `sys.exit` (which you aren't calling either), just set a flag to false and let the loop exit by itself

Comment: If that's your whole program. then the problem is that you haven't created an object of type AlienInvasion.  Try adding   `game = AlienInvasion()` and `game.run_game()`.

Comment: I have an if __name__ == __main__ line at the bottom that calls AlienInvasion

Comment: cool... where is it? (aside from the bottom...) can you show how it looks like?

Comment: @Matiiss I showed it and I don't understand what Spoly is recommending.

Comment: you need to call functions/methods for them to actually do something, _calling_ in Python literally means adding parentheses at the end of a name

Comment: so you're saying I just need to at parentheses such as "ai.run_game()"?

Comment: `ai.run_game` just needs to be `ai.run_game()`; to call a function you have to put parentheses at the end. Otherwise you're just referring to it (like if you want to pass the function itself as an argument to something, for instance, rather than pass the result of calling the function).

Comment: Oh my god, I'm so sorry for wasting your time it turns out I wrote pytgame in my "pytgame.display.flip" line. I changed it to pygame and it works, thank you and I'm sorry. Also your suggestion to add the parentheses worked, thank you both

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your program and came across a few functional errors in the code, but they are easy to fix.  Following is an adaptation of your program with some of the fixes in place.

```
import sys
import pygame

class AlienInvasion:

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))    # Substituted since I did not have the "Settings" file to import
        pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')

    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()             # Added this to gently end the game
                    exit()

            self.screen.fill((50, 50, 150))   # Substituted since I did not have the "Settings" file to import
            pygame.display.flip() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()           # One needs the parentheses to call this function
```

Probably the main issue with why your program just flashed the screen up was the last statement you have in your program was missing parentheses.  Instead of:

```
ai.run_game
```

one should have:

```
ai.run_game()
```

as you are calling a function.